# WSO2 APIM to WSO2 EI payload transfer issues - APIM throwing 101504 error

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I'm trying to send Json payload from WSO2 API Manager to ESB, for the **1st hit** its working fine and for the **second hit** its throwing **101504** Error. Similarly, not only for the 2nd hit its repeating the same if I'm trying to hit the service multiple times. Tried giving small and big payload but the Error is same. I can find through the **logs** only half payload is sent to ESB in failure cases. Is there any solution/input for these kind of issues?

Note : In both server(APIM 2.6, ESB 6.5) chunking is enabled

Answer (score 0):

With the available information, it is difficult to determine the exact cause of the issue. Since it is working without any issue for the first request, it might be related to the connections made with the server. With the available information, I could suggest you try to apply the following property before the call to the APIM [1].

```
<property name="NO_KEEPALIVE" scope="axis2" value="true"/>
```

If you continue to observe the issue, it is better to investigate further through a TCP dump.

[1]-https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/HTTP+Transport+Properties#HTTPTransportProperties-NO_KEEPALIVE